# Javascript: TypeError: cyclic object value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to stringify a javascript object, however when I do this a get the following error:

> TypeError: cyclic object value

I don't believe that my code contains any cyclic references (newServiceObject  is not referenced inside the object), so I do not understand why I am getting this message.

I want to turn my object that contains two properties and an array into a single string.

```
var serviceName = $('#newServiceNameBox').val();
        var serviceCodeElemList = $(".ServiceCodeName").map(function() { return $(this).html(); } );
        //create the new service object
        var newServiceObject = {ServiceId:-1, ServiceName: serviceName, ServiceCodes: serviceCodeElemList };

        var appendNewService = '&newService='+JSON.stringify(newServiceObject);
```

The error occurs on the last line (the JSON.Stringify() )  but I have no idea why!

Comment: can you post the JSON data in `newServiceObject` object ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is typically because you are trying to serialize a JavaScript object that has properties that point to each other in a cycle.

In your example, `newServiceObject.serviceCodeElemList` points to a `jQuery` object which does have cycles in it:  Its `context` property which points to a document object. A document object has pointers to DOM elements that have pointers back to the document through the `ownerDocument` property

```js
    var jqueryObj = $('div');
    console.log(jqueryObj.context); // Document object
    console.log(jqueryObj.context.body.firstChild.ownerDocument); // Document object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: see answer above! As per my question, I couldn't see anything obvious like this in my code. My guess is that something internal to the jquery object does this

Comment: @NeilP I've modified the answer to explain where the cycle is in jQuery objects.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that when using jquery to build the array, I should have included the `toArray()` method after the `map` function.

```
var list = $(".ServiceCodeName").map(function() { return $(this).html(); } ).toArray();
```

Therefore when the array is included in the object, it is a standard array and not a jquery object.