# How can I display my object observable data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am passing an id through a url in my angularfire2 app and collecting it in the onInit method

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.groupId = params['groupId'];
      // grab specific group
      this.group = this.af.database.object('/groups/'+this.groupId);
      this.group.subscribe(console.log);
    });
  }
```

the console.log shows perfectly the object I want but I can't then display it the HTML with `{{group.data}}` instead I get the string `[object Object]`.

I get the same result using a list observable too but in the console log I get a bunch of arrays of the data I want instead of 1 object so an object would be preferable if possible.

What do I have to do to be able to display the data?

Comment: Please post your model demonstrating the `data`. This issue can't be accurately diagnosed without knowing what that looks like. If `data` is a list-like object, for example, then the answer is different than if `data` is a simple key value pair.

Answer (score 2):

As per the code snippet you provide it look like `group` is Observable, so you can you `async` pipe in your template as follows,

```
<div>
   {{group | async}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

or if you want to log what is being omitted down the RXJS stream ..

```
this.activatedRoute.params.do(x => console.log(x)).subscribe
```

if in your HTML you want to display an Object you want to use the JSON pipe ..

instead of ..

```
{{ yourObject }}
```

you want ..

```
{{ yourObject | json }}
```

If you want to output a list ..

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item in list">
        {{ item | json }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice but now i am getting:
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./GroupsComponent class GroupsComponent - inline template:5:29 caused by: Converting circular structure to JSON
when i add the json pipe

Comment: the reason you are getting this is explained here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334580/javascript-typeerror-cyclic-object-value .. i will find a fix for you one sec

Comment: the reason this happens is because the | json pipe is, under the hood, simply using JSON.stringify (which converts an object to a string so you can read it) .. if JSON.stringify is passed a JSON object with cyclic references (references that point back to itself) then this error occurs - still looking for a fix

Comment: the best i can come up with is .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410162/circumvent-error-converting-circular-structure-to-json-when-doing-json-stringify .. which has various solutions - most of which involve using a library (like dojo) to overcome this problem

Comment: you could just stringify the property you are interested in or you could just console.log each one and inspect the object in the browser console tab - all the best - if you dont know what properties are on the Object just use Object.keys(yourObject)